# Nginx keeps redirecting to HTTPS for no apparent reason?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I've set up an Ubuntu VPS and everything is up and running but I keep getting redirected to HTTPS which I don't want.

This is my config:

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.0/ruby;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        server_name www.example.com localhost;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env    staging;
        root         /home/deploy/example.com/current/public;

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}
```

This is my output for `lynx example.com`:

```
Looking up example.com first
Looking up example.com
Making HTTP connection to example.com
Sending HTTP request.
HTTP request sent; waiting for response.
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Data transfer complete
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Using https://example.com/
Looking up example.com
Making HTTPS connection to example.com
Alert!: Unable to connect to remote host.

lynx: Can't access startfile http://example.com/
```

`/var/log/nginx/access.log`:

```
x.x.x.x - - [25/Apr/2016:09:25:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 301 0 "-" "Lynx/2.8.8rel.2 libwww-FM/2.14 SSL-MM/1.4.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2g"
```

Does anyone know why I keep getting redirected?

Comment: I think there's an option in Rails to force https, maybe this is what is causing the redirect. The nginx config doesn't seem to be the culprit here, unless there are other configuration files being applied.

Comment: Thanks! That was it: `config.force_ssl = false`. If you put this into an answer, I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a configuration option in rails to force the use of SSL. Try setting

```
config.force_ssl = false
```